# Add files from Team Foundation Server 2010 dev branch to main

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tfs

we are using TFS 2010 for version control and the development IDE is VS 2010. We only have two branches at the moment, Main and development branch.

Recently, we added new files to the development branch. My question is, how can I add those files to the Main branch? I can't do a merge because those files do not exist in the Main branch for TFS to merge to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do a merge from Dev to Main.

When you do the merge the new files in Dev that don't exist in Main will be added as a [Merge, Add] action. Then you check into Main.